# SelectOneRadio set time on selection

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, radiobuttonlist

I've been raking my brain trying to figure this one out.  I have a really simple requirement that's turning out to be a very interesting problem.

The requirement is to update a time stamp when the user chooses a selection in a radio button list.

So I have a radio button list:

```
...
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{mybean.myvalue}" >
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="A" itemValue="A"/>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="B" itemValue="B"/>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="C" itemValue="C"/>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="D" itemValue="D"/>
    <f:ajax render="timeBox" listener="#{measurements.captureTime('timeBox')}"/>
</h:selectOneRadio>
...
```

And a text box a little further down the page:

```
...
<h:outputText id="timeBox" value='#{measurements.timeBox}'>
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="HH:mm:ss"/>
</h:outputText>
...
```

And then in the backing bean I have the listener defined:

```
    ...
public void captureTime(String id){
       if(id.equals("timeBox"){
           timeBox = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
       }
}
    ...
```

But when I change the radio button, the value is not updating.  I'm pretty sure this is to do with the various phases of JSF (ie.  it's not being updated because of the problem in this post: http://balusc.blogspot.ca/2012/03/reset-non-processed-input-components-on.html)  but I'm not entirely sure how to fix it.. I'd really like to avoid including another library if possible.

As always let me know if you need more info and I will be happy to oblige.

Thanks!

**Edit**
The structure of these components is:

```
<h:form>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
     <h:select.../>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
     <h:output.../>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</h:form>
```

Comment: yeah I forgot to switch the name, it's fixed now.

Comment: Okay, are you using Mojarra or MyFaces? If I recall correctly, MyFaces don't swallow it if the ajax listener method takes a different argument than `AjaxBehaviorEvent`.

Comment: By the way, your render id `timeBox` is also not the same as the actual component id `timeFirstLeft`.

Comment: Thanks again, made the change.  I was trying to make the names more meaningful but it kind of backfired..

Comment: Okay. Is the method invoked or not? And are the radio button component and the output text component both in the same form?

Comment: The captureTime method is being invoked.  The radio button component is just a char.  The value being placed in the outputText component is a java.util.Date object.  This date is the date that the radio button was changed.  So basically the event fires and I want the textbox to update with the timestamp.  I'm updating the backing bean value here but it isn't showing up on the front end,  even after the ajax update.

Comment: Again, are the `<h:selectOneRadio>` and `<h:outputText id="timeBox">` placed inside the same `<h:form>`? If the output text is for example *outside* the form, then you'd need to change the `<f:ajax render>` value to specify its absolute client ID instead.

Comment: Added the structure to the original post

Comment: Is that the real JSF code or have you oversimplified it with its HTML output?

Comment: That is the current structure, I am using some basic html controls.  It's mostly due to the fact that I generated the view initially and expanded on it.

Comment: So you don't have duplicate elements with the same ID? Sorry, but this question is hard to answer as long as you don't show an SSCCE. All I can do is to recommend you to carefully read my answer on this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466977/close-all-expanded-rows-inside-a-uirepeat

Comment: Sweeeet, it was the id's..  Thanks man!

Comment: Nice. I'll repost it as an answer so that you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The given construct suggests that you've duplicate components with the same ID. Make sure that you don't actually have duplicate components with the same ID.